# C# return a list of files in a label that do not contain a string

Tags: c#

I am searching for `MIS` in a few `*.INI` files. Then I change the value for that entry and save the files again. I am now looking for a way the program will display a list of the INI files that do not contain the `MIS` entry.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        label1.Visible = false;
        label3.Visible = false;
        label4.Visible = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        label1.Visible = false;
        label3.Visible = false;
        label4.Visible = false;

        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@".\");
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.INI");

            if (Files.Length == 0)
            {
                label3.Visible = true;
                label3.Text = "No INI files found in the directory!";
                label3.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label4.Visible = true;
                label4.Text = "Ensure the program is run from inside the !MineIT folder";
                label4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
                foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
                {
                    string text = File.ReadAllText(file.Name);
                    const string PATTERN = @"MIS (?<Number>[\d\.]+)";
                    Match match = Regex.Match(text, PATTERN, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

                    if (match.Success == false)
                    {
                        label3.Visible = true;
                        label3.Text = "No MIS entry found in the INI file!";
                        label3.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        label4.Visible = true;
                        label4.Text = "Ensure MIS has been defined in the INI file";
                        label4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int index = match.Groups["Number"].Index;
                        int lenght = match.Groups["Number"].Length;

                        text = text.Remove(index, lenght);
                        text = text.Insert(index, "1");

                        label1.Text = ("SERVER ENABLED");
                        label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        label1.Visible = true;
                        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                        File.WriteAllText(file.Name, text);
                    }
                }
             }
        catch 
        {
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        label1.Visible = false;
        label3.Visible = false;
        label4.Visible = false;

        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@".\");
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.INI");

            if (Files.Length == 0)
            {
                label3.Visible = true;
                label3.Text = "No INI files found in the directory!";
                label3.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label4.Visible = true;
                label4.Text = "Ensure the program is run from inside the !MineIT folder";
                label4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
                {
                    string text = File.ReadAllText(file.Name);
                    const string PATTERN = @"MIS (?<Number>[\d\.]+)";
                    Match match = Regex.Match(text, PATTERN, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

                    if (match.Success == false)
                    {
                        label3.Visible = true;
                        label3.Text = "No MIS entry found in the INI file!";
                        label3.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        label4.Visible = true;
                        label4.Text = "Ensure MIS has been defined in the INI file";
                        label4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int index = match.Groups["Number"].Index;
                        int lenght = match.Groups["Number"].Length;

                        text = text.Remove(index, lenght);
                        text = text.Insert(index, "0");

                        label1.Text = ("SERVER DISABLED");
                        label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        label1.Visible = true;
                        pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                        File.WriteAllText(file.Name, text);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

I am very new to programming and I am hoping someone will have the heart to help me figure this out.

I have googled for 2 days and have not found much to help.

I want to display the result as:

```
label3.Text = "No MIS entry found in the INI files: a, b, c, d, e
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under `button1_Click` define list of strings that will hold filenames of files without MIS

```
private void button1_Click()
{
    List<string> filesWithoutMIS = new List<string>();
    // rest of your code
```

Later, when checking for MIS via Regex, add filename to list

```
if (!match.Success)
{
    filesWithoutMIS.Add(file.Name);
    label4.Visible = true;
    label4.Text = "Ensure MIS has been defined in the INI file";
    label4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

on the end of your method, after `foreach` loop, write info

```
label3.Text = "No MIS entry found in the INI files: " + string.Join(", ", filesWithoutMIS.ToArray());
```

Comment: @HendrikSidaway you can say thanks by marking answer as solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `List<string>` where you keep the names of the files without the required text, after the loop, check if you have names in that List and display everything

```
List<string> noMatch = new List<string>();
foreach(FileInfo file in Files)
{
    ...
    if (match.Success == false)
       noMatch.Add(file.Name);
    else
       ....
}

if(noMatch.Count > 0)
{
    label3.Visible = true;
    label3.Text = $"Files {string.Join(",", noMatch)} have no MIS entry !";
    label3.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    label4.Visible = true;
    label4.Text = "Ensure the program is run from inside the !MineIT folder";
    label4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```